# Does a presentation of a group correspond to a unique group?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

The definition of presentation of a group is as follows:

> If $G$ is generated by a subset $S$ and there is some collection of relations, say $R_{1}, R_{2}, \dots, R_{m}$(here each $R_{i}$ is an equation in the elements from $S\cup \{ 1 \}$) such that any relation among the elements of $S$ can be deduced from these, we shall call these generators and relations a **presentation** of $G$ and write
> $$
> G = \langle\ S \mid R_{1}, R_{2}, \dots R_{m}\ \rangle.
> $$

I understand that a group may have many presentations, but I want to know that if a presentation exactly corresponds to a unique group.

Here is my (possible) reasoning:

If we have two groups of the same presentation, then since the generators generate all the elements in group, we can map each product of generators in one group to the other, and since any relations of the generators can be derived from the relations given in the presentation, we can determine when two elements are exactly the same thus the map is well defined and a isomorphism. So a presentation corresponds to a unique group in the isomorphic sense.

If my reasoning is right, then for a given presentation, if I find a group which can have the same presentation, then that group is exactly the group that the presentation corresponding to, is that right?

Comment: This is a presentation, not a representation! Representations mean something completely different.

Comment: Two groups with the same presentations are going to be isomorphic.

Comment: @IrvingRabin Exactly what I wanted to confirm. Thank you.

Comment: I think it is more usual to define a group presentation as the quotient group of the free group on the generators with the normal closure of the relators of the presentation. With that definition a presentation clearly defines a unique group, and a presentation of a group $G$ is an isomorphism from the  group defined by the presentation to $G$.

Comment: Also, your definition appears to assume that the number of relations in the presentation is finite, but that is not necessarily true.

Comment: @DerekHolt What about the more intuitive definition which defines an equivalence class on the free group saying that two words are equivalent if one can be deduced from the other using the group axioms and the relators; it is equivalent to the quoitent group definition but is it not more intuitive? With the equivalence being a consequence of the first isomorphsim theorem?

Comment: @VivaanDaga Yes it might be more intuitive, but I prefer the quotient group definition as being more precise and concise. There is also a case for defining a group presentation by its universal property that any map from its generators to an arbitrary group $G$ that maps the defining relators to the identity extends to a homomorphism from the group defined by the presentation to $G$, but then you have to prove existence and uniqueness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are unique *up to isomorphism*. That is, for groups $G,H$ with a shared presentation $P$, we have

$$\boxed{G\cong H.}$$

For details, see Magnus *et al*.'s, *"Combinatorial Group Theory: Presentations of Groups in Terms of Generators and Relations."*

---

*Note*: This does not mean that $G,H$ are necessarily *equal*. For example, the groups $G=(\{-1,1\},\times)$ and $H=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ are clearly not equal and yet

$$P=\langle a\mid a^2\rangle$$

is a presentation for both.